# Anonymous Interface Callback in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, delegates

I'm making a videogame and I need clients and server to communicate (in Unity).

The message from the server needs to be converted to a specific type based on the request: for example, the registration process will return just a bool in case of success or not; the login process must return a lot of information in a dictionary for the user who logged in (level, experience, game progress, etc.)

In java I used to do something like this:

```
net().post(url.toString(), safeUrl, new Callback<String>()
{
    public void onFailure(Throwable t)
    {
        // do something to handle the failure...
    }

    public void onSuccess(String json)
    {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

Basically the net().post was sending a post http request to the server, and once it was done the server was calling the correct method.

I read that C# can't do this, but that delegates can achieve something similar, do you know how? so basically I just send to the post request a method as parameter and handle it? Also is it possible to use generic types to handle the different types of requests?

Or Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Works there as well, however there are also some suggestions for .NET 3.5 and upwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives here.

You can use `Action<string>` to pass in anonymous callbacks to your method.

**Or**...

you dive into the `async/await` world, which is the recommended approach.

---

### Using anonymous delegates

Your `Post` signature would look like this:

```
public void Post(string url, string safeUrl, Action<string> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onFailure);
```

Notice that you must have an argument for each callback result.

Inside your `Post` method, you should call the callbacks when done.

From the client (or caller), you would call it like this:

```
Post(url, safeUrl, response =>
{
   // Success callback body
}, exception =>
{
   // Failure callback body
});
```

---

### Using async/await (I don't know if this approach is supported in Unity)

Your `Post` signature would look like this:

```
public async Task<string> Post(string url, string safeUrl);
```

Inside your `Post` method, when sending the request you should use a method that support `async/await`, such as [HttpClient.PostAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh138242(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
// This is just an example
public async Task<string> Post(string url, string safeUrl)
{
     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
     string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return content;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
Task<string> fetchingResponse = Post(url, safeUrl);

// You can keep doing things while you wait for the response ...

try
{
    string response = await fetchingResponse;
    // Success logic here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Failure logic here
}
```

Notice that there are no callbacks.

Also, keep in mind that your caller method (i.e. the method that is executing `Post`) should also be anotated with `async` and should also return a `Task` or `Task<T>` instance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct equivalent to that in c#, however you may use delegates, e.g. as follows:

```
class Callback {
    private readonly Action<Exception> onFailure;
    private readonly Action<string> onSuccess;

    public CallBack(Action<Exception> onFailure, Action<string> onSuccess) {
        this.onFailure = onFailure;
        this.onSuccess = onSuccess;
    }

    public void FireFailure(Exception e) {this.OnFailure(e);}
    public void FireSuccess(string json) {this.OnSuccess(json);}
}
```

Now it is up to your `net().post`-method to fire the approriate events.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Throwable` in C#, he should use the `Exception` class.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yeap, you´re right, changed appropriately.